# Granting sql server database access to IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, sql-server-2012-express

I have an ASP NET APP that's trying to access a sql server database, when I run it, I get an error saying

> "Login Failed for user IIS **APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool**"

Searching the web I found that I should grant access to this user, so I executed the following script:

```
grant  execute on schema :: dbo to [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
```

It executed succesfully as a script for my database, but I still get the `"Login Failed"` error.

What's missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the user your DefaultAppPool is using to connect.

On your IIS manager check DefaultAppPool advanced properties and look for Identity. You need to give it a user with enough privileges, depending on what your site is going to do.

I usually create different AppPools for different sites depending on what they will do, for example, if your app will write documents to a folder on your server, the user of the AppPool will need writing access to that folder.

Also is not a good idea to use an administrator user, as it could lead to potential security breaches. However it could be a good way to check if your problem comes from there.

Comment: IN SSME I added a login for NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE ("NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red" in spanish), in user mappings gave it db_Owner role membership for the database. In IIS7.5, DefaultAppPool is set as ApplicationPoolIdentity (ProcessModel\Identity). Don't know what else to do... My site is a test site, I want to give it privileges for everything for starters

Answer (score -1):

I think I already know what it is. When I upgraded SQL Server Express, it installed a new server .\SQLEXPRESS (because I used "new sql instance"), remote connections where configured in this server and not LocalDB, my database was still in LocalDB. But now I get other error, maybe related to WCF Data Services...